# Enroll RFID Card using Zkteco in C#

Tags: c#, zkteco, zkemkeeper

I cannot enroll  RFID Card via C# application.
I could do fingerprint and face enrollment from c# application.

But I can't register a user RFID card  in ZKTECO Device using ZKemKeeper.dll

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance